# Trouble using a column from a derived table

Tags: mysql

SQL rookie and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong trying to use a derived table.

Test Tables:

```
Controller  
+---------+--------+------+  
| termID  | Net    | Type | 
+---------+--------+------+  
| T901    | F001   | P    |  
+---------+--------+------+  
| T902    | F001   | A    |  
+---------+--------+------+  


Privilege  
+---------+--------+  
| termID  | Net    |  
+---------+--------+  
| T903    | F001   |  
+---------+--------+ 



Terminal  
+---------+------+  
| termID  | Act  | 
+---------+------+  
| T901    | Y    |  
| T902    | Y    |  
| T903    | Y    |  
+---------+------+
```

This seems to work -->

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT termid from controller where net="F001"
    UNION
    SELECT termid from privilege where net="F001"
     ) att1
JOIN terminal
ON att1.termid=terminal.termid;
```

Giving:

```
+---------+--------+------+  
| termID  | termID | Act  |  
+---------+--------+------+  
| T901    | T901   | Y    |  
| T902    | T902   | Y    |  
| T903    | T903   | Y    |  
+---------+--------+------+
```

This seems to work -->

```
SELECT att1.termid
FROM (
    SELECT termid from controller where net="F001"
    UNION
    SELECT termid from privilege where net="F001"
     ) att1
JOIN terminal
ON att1.termid=terminal.termid;
```

Giving:

```
+---------+  
| termID  |  
+---------+  
| T901    |  
| T902    |  
| T903    |   
+---------+
```

However, this returns: "Unknown column 'att1.Act' in 'field list' -->

```
SELECT att1.Act
FROM (
    SELECT termid from controller where net="F001"
    UNION
    SELECT termid from privilege where net="F001"
     ) att1
JOIN terminal
ON att1.termid=terminal.termid;
```

Since the others "worked" in that they say the columns, I don't understand why it can't see this particular column.

What do I have to do to get access to the derived table's column?

If anyone is in the mood to tell me how I should have approached this, I'm ultimately trying to determine if all the terminals in the Controller or Privilege tables are all active or all not active in the terminal table.  This was my first try (but fails in the subset of code up above).

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT att1.Act
    FROM (
        SELECT termid from controller where net="F001"
        UNION
        SELECT termid from privilege where net="F001"
         ) att1
    JOIN terminal
    ON att1.termid=terminal.termid
     ) att2;
```

Comment: Include `Act` into your sub-query SELECT lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your broken SQL:

```
SELECT att1.Act
FROM (
    SELECT termid from controller where net="F001"
    UNION
    SELECT termid from privilege where net="F001"
     ) att1
JOIN terminal
ON att1.termid=terminal.termid;
```

is broken because the column Act isn't defined on the table att1.

Try starting your query with

```
SELECT att1.termId, terminal.act
```

and see if that works better for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works   I guess I was thinking that after you create a derived table you should get the attributes from there; but bad on me for not thinking to try it the other way.  I can now show up for work on Monday.